# Raspberry Pi 2 low bogoMIPs number

Tags: pi-2

I've recently bought a Raspberry Pi 2 to develop some embedded software on. Looking at the specs of the new Pi I thought it would have plenty of power for my application.

When I googled a lot of people mentioned that the bogoMIPs number they saw in `/proc/cpuinfo` was around 600. What I see is the following:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor       : 1
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor       : 2
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

processor       : 3
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 5 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xc07
CPU revision    : 5

Hardware        : BCM2709
Revision        : a01041
Serial          : 0000000086b30467
```

My operating system is:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

I am powering the Pi from a powered USB hub. When I first booted the Pi I did not choose the overclocking option.

Is there anything I can do to increase the processing speed?

Answer (score 2):

It may be that BogoMIPS on ARM isn't measuring the CPU speed at all.  38.40 MHz seems to be too much of a coincidence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips#Timer-based_delays

> In 2012, ARM contributed a new udelay implementation allowing the
>   system timer built into many ARMv7 CPUs to be used instead of a
>   busy-wait loop.

...

> One side effect of this change is that the BogoMIPS value will reflect the timer frequency, not the CPU's core frequency. Typically the timer frequency is much lower than the processor's maximum frequency, and some users may be surprised to see an unusually low BogoMIPS value when comparing against systems that use traditional busy-wait loops.

Answer (score 1):

BogoMips is not a measure of relative speed between processors.  Google.

Ignore BogoMips.

The Pi2 is likely to be 4-6 times as fast as the early model Pis.

If it's not fast enough you'll have to overclock, but it is not as over-clockable as the early model Pis.